# Fastreport and Delphi Berlin: How to put multiple records fields in one line

Tags: delphi

I would like to make a master-detail report with fast reports in Delphi Berlin where the detail field date should be printed next to each other in one line. Can someone tell me which property must be set for printing next to each other?

Thanks 
[image]

ANd here is the result:

[image]

Comment: You can use a multicolumn band to get fields from multiple records in the same line.

Comment: @Brian thanks, could you please tell me more about it. I am novice with fastreport. I could do the master-detail successfully but the detail, is printed one date in each line. see above.

Comment: For the DetailData1 band set the Columns property to the number of columns you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works!

Comment: Moreover I had to set the Columnswidth too a small value.

Comment: Updated the answer to mention setting the width as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a multi-column detail band by setting the Columns property of the band to the number of columns you want instead of the default of one column and providing a ColumnWidth (note: the dark squares on the designer are 1 wide).

[image]